# Number of solutions of $am \equiv bn \pmod{q}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, exponential-sums, congruences

Let $q$ be a (large) prime. Let $N$ be a positive integer of size${}\approx \sqrt{q}$. Let $\mathcal{M}$ be an arbitrary subset of $\{1, \dots, q\},$ such that $\mathcal{M}$ has cardinality $N$. Question:
is there a non-trivial upper bound for the number of solutions of
$$
a m \equiv b n \qquad  \pmod q,
$$
subject to $1 \leq a,b \leq N$ and $m,n \in \mathcal{M}$?

The trivial upper bound is $N^3$, since given $a,m,b$, there is at most one choice for $n$.

As a heuristics, for a "random" set $\mathcal{M}$, one would expect around $N^2$ many solutions (there are $N^2 \approx q$ possibilities for the value of $am$ as $a$ runs through $\{1, \dots, N\}$ and $m$ runs through $\mathcal{M}$, so typically each element of $\{1,\dots, q\}$ should be represented just a few times in the form $am$).

Is there a general upper bound of order $N^{2 + \varepsilon}$ for the number of solutions?

To me this seems to be related to sum-product problem from additive combinatorics and to the Erdös multiplication table problem.

(One could also imagine variants of the problem, where $a,b$ come from a general set of cardinality $N$, but not necessarily the set of the first $N$ integers. One could also consider the case when $N$ is not of order $\approx \sqrt{q}$, but significantly smaller/larger.)

Comment: You should learn how to use `\bmod` and `\pmod` and how to include {curly braces} in MathJax and in LaTeX, thus: $$ \{1,\ldots,q\} $$

Comment: Specifically to @MichaelHardy's [point](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/446965/number-of-solutions-of-am-equiv-bn-pmodq#comment1154805_446965), if you are curious how any bit of TeX was produced, you can right click on it and choose "Show Math As > TeX commands" to see, in this case, `\{1,\ldots,q\}`.  But, while we're discussing TeX, the AMS introduced, and MathJax respects, what I called "semantic dots": in this case `\dotsc`, for dots between commas, which are lowered; but there are also `\dotsb` for dots between binary operators, which are centred, and several others.

Comment: Well, okay, thanks, to be honest I don't care to much about the precise coding, as long as I am convinced that everybody can read and understand what I am writing.

Comment: @KurisutoAsutora : Donald Knuth created TeX in order to create BEAUTIFUL documents. You look at the same text in two fonts and think one looks very good and the other hideous, and most people don't think about the FACT that the difference results from many little differences that they don't notice, in the design and layout of characters. If you improve those little differences some people object that no one will even notice those little improvements. One cannot miss the point more completely than that.

Comment: If you allow $\gcd(a,b)\neq 1$, then there may be more than one solution for any given $m, n$. [OEIS entry A015614](https://oeis.org/A015614) gives the number of elements in the set $\{(x,y): 1\le x\le y\le n, \gcd(x,y)=1\}$ with asymptotic limit $a(n)\approx \frac{3 n^2}{\pi^2}$.

Comment: Are there not $N^2$ solutions for the case $m=n$?

Comment: Yes, the "diagonal" with $m=n$ contributes $N^2$ to the number of solutions.

Answer (score 4):

I made a fatal mistake in my attempt at obtaining a simple asymptotic formula for the number $J$ of solutions to the congruence with the given restrictions. Undaunted, I come back with the proof of a general upper bound for $J$ which I learned from M. Z. Garaev back in the day.

Let us assume that $q \notin \mathcal{M}$. By the orthogonality relations for Dirichlet characters modulo $q$, it follows that

$$J = \frac{1}{p-1} \sum_{\chi} \sum_{\substack{m, \, n \in \mathcal{M}\\ 1 \leq a, \, b\leq N}} \chi(amb^{\ast}n^{\ast})$$

where $t^{\ast}$ denotes the multiplicative inverse of $t$ modulo $q$. By resorting to the multiplicativity of Dirichlet characters modulo $q$, we may rewrite the previous formula as

$$ J = \frac{1}{p-1} \sum_{\chi} \left|\sum_{m \in \mathcal{M}} \chi(m)\right|^{2} \left|\sum_{1 \leq a \leq N} \chi(a)\right|^{2}.$$

Then, if $n_{0} \in (1, \infty) \cap \mathbb{N}$, Hölder's inequality gives

$$ J \leq \left(\frac{1}{p-1}\sum_{\chi} \left|\sum_{m \in \mathcal{M}} \chi(m) \right|^{2\cdot \frac{n_{0}}{n_{0}-1}}\right)^{\frac{n_{0}-1}{n_{0}}} \left(\frac{1}{p-1} \sum_{\chi} \left|\sum_{1 \leq a \leq N} \chi(a)\right|^{2 \cdot n_{0} }\right)^{\frac{1}{n_{0}}}. \qquad (1)$$

We can obtain a nontrivial upper bound for the expression in the first pair of parentheses by resorting to the fact that

$$ \frac{1}{p-1} \sum_{\chi} \left|\sum_{m \in \mathcal{M}} \chi(m)\right|^{2} = |\mathcal{M}|$$

and proceeding thus:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{p-1} \sum_{\chi} \left|\sum_{m \in \mathcal{M}} \chi(m)\right|^{2 \cdot \frac{n_{0}}{n_{0}-1}} &=& \frac{1}{p-1} \sum_{\chi} \left|\sum_{m \in \mathcal{M}} \chi(m)\right|^{2} \left|\sum_{m \in \mathcal{M}} \chi(m)\right|^{\frac{2}{n_{0}-1}}\\ &\leq& |\mathcal{M}| \left|\mathcal{M}\right|^{\frac{2}{n_{0}-1}}\\ &=& |\mathcal{M}|^{\frac{n_{0}+1}{n_{0}-1}}. \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad (2)
\end{eqnarray*}

In order to estimate the expression in the second pair of parentheses in $(1)$, we note that

$$\frac{1}{p-1} \sum_{\chi} \left| \sum_{1 \leq a \leq N} \chi(a) \right|^{2n_{0}} = \frac{1}{p-1} \sum_{\chi} \sum_{1 \leq a_{1}, \ldots, a_{n_{0}}, u_{1}, \ldots, u_{n_{0}} \leq N} \chi(a_{1}\cdots a_{n_{0}}\cdot u_{1}^{\ast} \cdots u_{n_{0}}^{\ast});$$

therefore,

$$\frac{1}{p-1} \sum_{\chi} \left| \sum_{1 \leq a \leq N} \chi(a) \right|^{2n_{0}}$$

is equal to the number of solutions to the congruence

$$ a_{1}\cdots a_{n_{0}} \equiv u_{1} \cdots u_{n_{0}} \pmod{q}$$

where

$$1 \leq a_{1}, \ldots, a_{n_{0}}, u_{1}, \ldots, u_{n_{0}} \leq N.$$ The congruence can be expressed as the equation

$$a_{1} \cdots a_{n_{0}} = u_{1} \cdots u_{n_{0}} + qz$$

for some integer $z \in [-(N^{n_{0}}-1)/q, (N^{n_{0}}-1)/q]$. Hence, for any fixed selection of $u_{1}, \ldots, u_{n_{0}},$ and $z$, in their corresponding ranges, each of the $a_{1}, \ldots, a_{n_{0}}$ has to be a positive divisor of the product $u_{1} \cdots u_{n_{0}} + qz$. Since $1 \leq u_{1} \cdots u_{n_{0}} + qz < 2N^{n_{0}}$, the number of such $n_{0}$-tuples $(a_{1}, \ldots, a_{n_{0}})$ is $N^{o(1)}$. It follows that

$$\frac{1}{p-1} \sum_{\chi} \left| \sum_{1 \leq a \leq N} \chi(a) \right|^{2n_{0}}  \leq \left(\frac{2N^{n_{0}}}{q}+1\right)N^{n_{0}}N^{o(1)}< \left(\frac{N^{n_{0}}}{q}+1\right) N^{n_{0}+o(1)}. \qquad (3).$$

From $(1)$, $(2)$, and $(3)$ we conclude that

$$ J \leq |\mathcal{M}|^{\frac{n_{0}+1}{n_{0}}} \left(\frac{N}{q^{1/n_{0}}}+1\right) N^{1+o(1)}= \left(\frac{N}{q^{1/n_{0}}}+1\right) N^{1/n_{0}}N^{2+o(1)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Really a comment, but I wanted to include a graph.

Can you figure out what happens if you take $\mathcal{M}$ to be $\{1,\cdots,N\}$? Then it does not matter what $q$ is as long as it is larger than $N^2.$ For each possible product $1 \leq r \leq N^2$ let $f(r)$ be the number of factors $a\mid r$ with $\frac{r}{N} \leq a \leq N$. Then the number you want is the sum of $f(r)^2$. It seems it might be possible to work that out. Of course it might be asymptotic to $N^2$. Here are the exponents for $20 \leq N \leq 100$

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I don't get exactly what you mean, I think your notation is not in accordance with the one in the statement of the question. Maybe your $q$ should be $N$, and $p$ should be $q$?

Comment: Yes,  you are correct. I fixed it.

Comment: I agree that this is a very interesting special case. It's possible that someone has worked it out, but I am not aware of a solution. In this setup the aspect of taking a reduction mod q completely disappears. The problem should be closely related to Erdös' multiplication table (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Tenenbaum%E2%80%93Ford_constant), which however asks for the cardinality of the set of numbers $r$ that are being represented, but not the respective number of representations.